# How do I apply the changes to the .zshrc file after editing it?

Tags: zsh, dot-files

I just edited the .zshrc file to configure [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) on FreeBSD, for example to update the *PATH* system variable.

```bsh
path+=/usr/local/openjdk12/bin
```

How do I make the changes take effect?

Must I log out and log in again? Is there a way to immediately run that file?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Restart zsh

Zsh reads `.zshrc` when it starts. You don't need to log out and log back in. Just closing the terminal and opening a new one gives you your new `.zshrc` in this new terminal. But you can make this more direct. Just tell zsh to relaunch itself:

```
exec zsh
```

If you run this at a zsh prompt, this replaces the current instance of zsh by a new one, running in the same terminal. The new instance has the same *environment* variables as the previous one, but has fresh *shell* (non-exported) variables, and it starts a new history (so it'll mix in commands from other terminals in typical configurations). Any background jobs are disowned.

## Reread `.zshrc`

You can also tell zsh to re-read `.zshrc`. This has the advantage of preserving the shell history, shell variables, and knowledge of background jobs. But depending on what you put in your `.zshrc`, this may or may not work. Re-reading `.zshrc` runs commands which may not work, or not work well, if you run them twice.

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

There are just too many things you can do to enumerate everything that's ok and not ok to put in `.zshrc` if you want to be able to run it twice. Here are just *some* common issues:

- If you append to a variable (e.g. `fpath+=(~/.config/zsh)` or `chpwd_functions+=(my_chpwd)`), this appends the same elements again, which may or may not be a problem.
- If you define aliases, and also use the same name as a command, the command will now run the alias. For example, this works:

  ```
  function foo { … }
  alias foo='foo --common-option'
  ```

  But this doesn't, because the second time the file is sourced, `foo ()` will expand the alias:

  ```
  foo () { … }
  alias foo='foo --common-option'
  ```
- If you patch an existing zsh function, you'll now be patching your own version, which will probably make a mess.
- If you do something like “swap the bindings of two keys”, that won't do what you want the second time.

Answer (score 5):

Changes to a shells initialisation files will be active in the *next* shell that you start, for example if you bring up a new graphical terminal or log out and in again.  If you've made changes that should affect your desktop environment in some way (I don't know what kind of change that may be), then logging out and in again would be required.

You *could* source the file with `. /path/to/filename` (`. ~/.zshrc` in your case) or start a new shell session from the command line with `zsh`, but this is almost never a good idea as it may have unwanted consequences such as adding duplicate paths to the `$PATH` variable or starting extra `ssh-agent` processes or whatever it is you may be doing in that file.  The changes would also not be visible program that have already been started.

For a change such as just adding to the `$PATH` unconditionally, you could obviously just run the added command in the current shell:

```
$ path+=/usr/local/openjdk12/bin
```

This would (in `zsh`) add the `/usr/local/openjdk12/bin` directory to the end of `$PATH` (and to the end of the `$path` array in `zsh`) in the current shell session.  Again, this change to `$PATH` would not affect already running processes.

Comment: Those _unwanted consequences_ would also be triggered if the OP just started a new `zsh` shell. It's customary to do `typeset -U path` in `zsh` so the `$PATH` entries remain always unique. `$PATH` is better set in `~/.zprofile` though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "$PATH is better set in ~/.zprofile though." Why is that?

Comment: @MarlonRichert, because it's more of a login session setting than a shell settings though those distinctions are not as clear these days that you don't always login via a shell.

Answer (score 4):

You could source the new file, which would work for some changes, possibly including updating the PATH variable (depending on other lines). However, sourcing it would simply run `.zshrc` again, and you might execute unexpected duplicate commands. Moreover, if there were deleted lines from the old `.zshrc`, then they wouldn't be "erased" from the session.

The cleanest way is to just log out and in again. You'd only need to do it for the terminal session, not the whole desktop environment.

Answer (score 2):

## Oh My Zsh

[*Oh My Zsh*](https://ohmyz.sh/) is an open-source, community-driven framework for managing your Zsh configuration.

After installation, you can run the following command:

```sh
omz reload
```

to reload the `.zshrc` configuration file.

Comment: This effectively [runs `exec zsh`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/cli.zsh#L632), which is already mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for clarifying that. I thought it doesn't actually restart zsh, so you don't lose anything session related, like variables. But I guess I was wrong. I tried to search on the web for what `omz reload` does, but I couldn't find anything more specific than "it reloads the configuration".