# Why do I have to use this command twice to execute it?

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, alias, cd-command

I made an alias `alias goto="cd $@ && source ~/.zshrc"` and it works, but only if I execute it twice. Even after I execute it twice in one shell, and if I want to move to another dir, I must again execute it twice. Why is that and how can I change that?

I need to type two times `goto <dir>`. The first time, I am still in the normal dir and the second time, I got to my destination. I need to source .zshrc, because I have a check for the path:

```
CURRENT=$PWD
AT_HOME=0
AT_ROOT=0

if [ $PWD = $HOME ]; then
    AT_HOME=1
elif [ $PWD = / ]; then
    AT_ROOT=1
else
    cd ../

    if [ $PWD = $HOME ]; then
        AT_HOME=1
    elif [ $PWD = / ]; then
        AT_ROOT=1
    else
        cd ../

        if [ $PWD = $HOME ]; then
            AT_HOME=1
        elif [ $PWD = / ]; then
            AT_ROOT=1
        fi
    fi
fi

cd $CURRENT

if [ $AT_HOME = 0 ]; then
    if [ $AT_ROOT = 0 ]; then
        ZSH_THEME="prompt-basename"
    else
        ZSH_THEME="prompt-normal"
    fi
else
    ZSH_THEME="prompt-normal"
fi
```

And it gives me full path (even at /usr/lib/jvm/java-13/bin) and when I source ~/.zshrc, it gives me the path I want (.../java-13/bin). By the way, replacing `&&` with `;` does not work neither.

Thanks!

*This is my first Question at stackxchange.com, so please don't be too rough.

Comment: What is in `~/.zshrc`? Something in there might be tripping up zsh's alias system? Maybe if you edit your question to state what you are trying to do with the alias, someone who knows a cleaner and efficient way to do so will contribute an answer?

Comment: It would be interesting to know the definition of "it works". What is the outcome when it does not work? Also, what do you have to enter twice - `goto` or the `alias` command? While I can assume the most likely answers to these questions, it's better that you clarify them.

Comment: Aliases don't use arguments, the `$@` isn't what you think it is there.

Comment: Does it work when you use `;` instead of `&&`? If so, then `cd`'s exit status is not 0, which means it failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, aliases are not functions and do not accept arguments. Rather, aliases are simple substitutions: When you type `goto foo` on the command line and press Enter, the shell simply replaces `goto` with the value of the alias, before executing the command line.

Therefore, `$@` does not expand to the arguments passed to your alias. In fact, in this case, it expands to the **arguments passed to shell or the script you're sourcing**. This is why `goto` works correctly the second time: You have now passed a directory as an argument when sourcing your `.zshrc` file and `$@` will expand to that argument when you declare the alias again.

Additionally, since you're using `"`double quotes`"`, `$@` expands **immediately when you declare the alias.** To see that this is the case, right after your shell has started up, type `alias` without arguments to view your aliases.

If you want `goto` to be able to handle arguments, you should declare it as a function: `goto() { cd $@ && ... }`

*However,* as a rule, ⚠️[you should **not** `source ~/.zshrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532591/413610). Depending on what's in your dotfiles, this can lead to all sorts of problems.

Instead, if you've made changes to your `.zshrc` file and you want to apply them, you should either restart your terminal (by closing the current tab/window and opening a new one) or restart the shell (by typing `exec $SHELL`).

Comment: The quotes will explain why OP has to "run it twice for it to work". The first time, the directory is an argument to `~/.zshrc` as it gets sourced, so when the alias gets redefined during that, the `$@` in the alias expands to the directory. So the second time the alias does have `cd <whatever-path>`, and it works.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Why should you not source `~/.zshrc`? Opening a new terminal will source it anyway, so why would there be an issue if you source it manually?

Comment: @terdon Because it's been sourced already when your shell started up and the order in which commands are run can matter. As a simple example, put `ls() { command ls "$@" | less }; alias ls='ls -AF'` into your `.zshrc` file, restart your shell, then `source ~/.zshrc`. Now you get an error `zsh: defining function based on alias 'ls'`. And that's only a fairly innocuous example. Things can get much more hairy than that, especially when your `.zshrc` in turn sources 3rd-party files.

Comment: That doesn't actually give me an error in zsh. But even if you can find some edge case that does, I am surprised you seem so adamant against this. I have been changing my `~/.bashrc` and then sourcing it for many years and have never once encountered a problem. Maybe I have been lucky, but it seems more likely that what you are describing isn't a very common problem. Or perhaps it is special to zsh? Come teach me here: [Is there any reason to avoid sourcing the shell's configuration file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/649665)

Comment: @terdon Read this answer for a more in-depth explanation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532591/413610

Comment: Actually, all the answers on that question are good.

Comment: In particular, this line sticks out to me as always being a problem when doing `source ~/.zshrc`, no matter what you do in there: 'Moreover, if there were deleted lines from the old .zshrc, then they wouldn't be "erased" from the session.'

Answer (score 0):

Marlon's answer works. Instead of making an alias, I did following function:

```
function goto {
    cd $@ && exec $SHELL
}
```

And it works perfectly. I also remarked, that sourcing ~/.zshrc takes longer and longer after every call of `goto`.