# create an alias on ZSH but need to type it twice

Tags: zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to create an alias on ZSH.

The aim of the alias is to activate a python virtualenv.

I've put a line in my `.zshrc`

```
alias SOU="source /home/andykw/.zshrc && source $(setopt extendedglob &&  ls -d .^git/)/bin/activate"
```

Often I need to change virtual environment with activating a virtual environment in one of the folder, then switching to another folder and activate another virtual environment.

Example: Let's say I'm working with the folder `flask_rest` and I have to work on another project, `django_rest`, I will need to deactivate the `flask_rest` environment and activate the `django_rest` environment.

Instead of doing it several times with the command line `source <folder_name>/bin/activate` then go with another folder `source <another_folder_name>/bin/activate`, I only need to type `SOU`.

Hope it makes the context clearer.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu with a Windows Subsystem Linux.

Comment: Can you explain the objective a bit more clearly? Is the idea that you want to find the _single_ `activate` file that is in `./*/bin/activate`? Can there be more than one? Will you not know the name of the file? Can't you just do `source .*/bin/activate`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by only once? If you now want to source a different env, you need to run the command again, isn't that what you want? Are you expecting something that will automatically source the env file every time you move to a new directory?

Comment: @terdon your first comment was spot-on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is an alias that finds the *single* `./.*/bin/activate` file in the current directory tree and sources it, then all you need is:

```
alias SOU='source. */bin/activate'
```

If the glob `.*/bin/activate` matches multiple files, only the first one will be sourced. Your `~/.zshrc` file should be sourced every time you open a new non-login interactive shell session, and you probably don't want to be sourcing it multiple times. I suggest you open a new question to try and understand why you seem to need to source it explicitly.

Comment: glob expansion doesn't occur within double quotes. If you remove those doubles quotes, not that if the glob expands to more than one file, the ones after the first one will end up in `$1`, `$2`... inside the code in the first.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
SOU() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  local f
  for f (~/.zshrc ~/.(^git)/bin/activate(N.)) source $f || return
}
```

For `SOU` to source your `~/.zshrc` and whatever file called `bin/activate` in hidden directories other than `.git` in your home directory (ignoring the fact that it doesn't seem to make much sense to me).

You may also want to add the `U` and `r` qualifiers to limit to files that you own, and that are readable by the owner.

That defines a *function* rather than an *alias*. Aliases are more for csh users. Bourne-like shells have proper programming constructs like functions, though aliases can still be useful there in some corner cases, when you *do* want it to be handled as text replacements or if the alias needs to do changes in the scope of the caller, none of which seem to be the case here.

You can either put that function definition in your `~/.zshrc` or add it as an autoloadable function in one of your `$fpath` directories. See `info zsh autoloading` for details.

In any case sourcing `~/.zshrc` does not *undo* what sourcing `thosedirs/bin/activate` files do. It just *redoes* whatever is in `~/.zshrc` again (which could end up by undoing some of the changes brought by `bin/activate` but that would be by accident) and if some of those changings are additions, they will end-up accumulating among [other problems](/q/649665).

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Chazélas, how do you put it in .zshrc, please?

Comment: @AndyK, the same way you put your `alias` line. With a text editor for instance.

Comment: I've put the function in my zshrc and I cannot activate it...

Comment: @AndyK, make sure you also remove your `SOU` alias. What happens when you type `SOU` or with `(){ set -o localoptions -o xtrace; SOU;}`?

Comment: chazélas I've created another function called SOU1 instead of SOU. No error, just one thing that bugged me: When I do a `source .zshrc`, the charging is stalling.

Comment: @AndyK why are you sourcing `~/.zshrc` in the first place? That should already have been sourced when you first opened the latest interactive shell session and it [can be a bad idea to source it again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/649665/22222).